# SQL - How to embed LOVs?

Tags: sql, lov

I'm trying to suggest DB structure. There is little problem and I hope anyone can help me. There are following tables:

`VEHICLE` (basic entity with shared properties)

1. id
2. kind_id

`KIND` (personal car, utility vehicle)

1. id
2. name

`KIND_SPECIFIC_EQUIPMENT` (air-condition, airbag....) - possible equipment for specific kind

1. id
2. kind_id
3. name

`CAR_EQUIPMENT` (just link-table) - equipment for concrete car

1. vehicle_id
2. kind_specific_equipment_id

My problem is, that I need to add "`list of values`" for some equipment.
For example:

My kind of vehicle is "`personal car`" and "`kind_specific_equipment`" is "`air-condition`". There can be more kind of air-conditions (automatic, manual...) Do anyone known how I can do that?

Comment: replace "air-condition" with "automatic-air-condition" and "manual-air-condition".

Comment: But the "air-condition" is major table. The "automatic or manual" is type of air-condition. There is no possibility to insert type straight. There is possible that user know he has air-condition, but he doesn't know what type. I need to do it like VOL.

Comment: So, create a table `kind_specific_equipment_attributes(equipment_id, name, value)`.

Comment: Hey mate, now I know how to do that. create table `attributes` how you said, and like primary key do auto-increment and foreign key do equipment_id. I'm really tired today (Friday afternoon). Thanks much